# How to make this Foundation 6 website run in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

In today's guessing game, I have inherited this website project from the previous inhabitant of my desk, but I don't know how to run this site within visual studio, or, for that matter, outside of visual studio. As far as I can tell, this website project is written with Foundation 6 and Handlebars, but the project structure doesn't exactly match the default templates that I have seen when looking at Foundation or Handlebars. The rest of the solution (not shown) runs just fine, with no issues, but it's not written like this. It's all the normal .aspx type stuff.

I've tried to set this website project as the Startup Project, but when it builds and runs I get a 403 error (Forbidden). If I simply try to browse to the default or index pages, I get (see image below). Something is definitely missing, but I don't know how to tell what. Also, we have this page active in a dev server, and it works just fine, but again, idk how, or how to find out how.

Any idea of what I'm missing or suggestions on what steps I need to take to troubleshoot to get this thing to launch properly?

Thanks!

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What is in package.json in the `scripts`?

Comment: Did you try running `gulp` after installing it?

Comment: Not enough room in the comments to show. But lots of stuff from Zurb, like foundation-sites, jquery, motion-ui, what-input, gulp devDependencies, foundation-cli, and more. As for running gulp after installing - I didn't install anything, this is how it came. So - I found the solution. I looked at the Readme.md, found out that this is "This is the official ZURB Template for use with [Foundation for Sites]" and that infrastructure I thought was on my machine wasn't. So I followed the instructions, and voila...I was able to get it to run using "foundation watch".

Comment: `foundation watch` is basically just `npm start`, see https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/watch.js#L26

Comment: Also you can always add the info to your question for others.